# How to change image visibility in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visibility, onmouseover, onmouseout

I tried this, with no success :

**JS :**

```
function Hide() {
    alert('Hide');
    document.getElementById('I').style.visibility = 'none';

}

function show() {
    alert('Show');
    document.getElementById('I').style.visibility = 'visible';

}
```

**Code Behind :**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="Hide()" runat="server">Mouse Here</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:Image Visible="false" ImageUrl="~/Images/V.png" ID="I" runat="server" />
```

I added the alerts just to check if this active the function, and it is.

any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `display: none` if you want the element to not take up space. `visiblity: hidden` for if you still want the element to take up the space. Looks like you're mixing the two.

Comment: you can use  style display:none as well

Answer (score 4):

change `visibility` to `hidden` not `none`

```
function Hide() {
    alert('Hide');
    document.getElementById('I').style.visibility = 'hidden';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

While [Munawir's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067579/how-to-change-image-visibility-in-javascript/36067730#36067628) correct and answer your question, IMO it's better to use `display` instead when you want to `show/hide` elements it's more efficient for this purpose.

> `display:none` means that element will not appear on the page at all, There will be no space allocated for it.
>
> `visibility:hidden` the element is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page.

**Example :**

```
function Hide() {
    alert('Hide');
    document.getElementById('I').style.display = 'none';
        
}

function show() {
    alert('Show');
    document.getElementById('I').style.display = 'block';
       
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, Thanks!

 but it work only without the `Atributes Visible="false"`,
 also tried to changed at !ispostback, but it is not working... 
And I need that the page will start when I can't see the image.

I also have problem when the page is connected to a `MasterPage`

Answer (score 0):

Your code

`document.getElementById('I').style.visibility = 'none';`

Is wrong it should be

`document.getElementById('I').style.visibility = 'hidden';`

Also remember, setting element visibility to hidden will hide the element but still occupy space on the screen,

If you don't want the element to occupy space when hidden, then you must use `display :none;`

`document.getElementById('I').style.display = 'none';`

Then you can make it visible using

`document.getElementById('I').style.display = 'block';`

Comment: ok, Thanks!
but it work only without the `Atributes Visible="false"`,
also tried to changed at `!ispostback`, but it is not working...